# Unable to change text size of HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, font-size

My code is unable to change the font-size of the text content of the HTML page.

Here is my Code:

```
let size=document.querySelector('#content').style.fontSize

document.querySelector('#largeText').onclick= function(){
    size="40px"
}
document.querySelector('#normalText').onclick= function(){
    size="20px"
}
document.querySelector('#smallText').onclick= function(){
    size="12px"
}
```

and here is my HTML. I am pasting here only HTML that defines the buttons to change text:

```
<div>
    <button id="smallText" class="mx-2 my-2 px-2">
        small
    </button>
    <button id="normalText"  class="mx-2 my-2 px-2">
        normal
    </button>
    <button id="largeText"  class="mx-2 my-2 px-2">
        large
    </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many reasons it would not work. One is the "size =" affectations where the "size" variable value is set, not the actual value in the document. so size="40px" should be something like document.querySelector('#content').style.fontSize = ...

Answer (score 1):

You are just overriding your variable.

Save `let style = document.querySelector('#content').style` as a variable and use `style.fontSize = '40px'` then, to maintain the object reference.

**Edit:**

With "maintaining the object reference" I mean that the `.fontStyle` property works like a setter and getter function and just appears to be a attribute of the CSSStyleDeclaration object. If you just read the value of the getter and store it's result, the actual effect of changing the value resulting in a change of the elements style is lost.

For more see [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) and [ElementCSSInlineStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style) objects on MDN, as well as [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).

If you had a helpful answer for your question, you can mark it as accepted. It would not only help the one who wrote it, but also others who have the same problem and come across this question while searching.

Comment: that was useful. but can you tell me why i can not assign it till the fontSize. Can you explain what you mean by maintaining the object reference.

Comment: @noob_dev17 I updated my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common function and pass the required font-size to the function on `onclick` like below

```
onclick="changeTextSize(10);"
```

```js
function changeTextSize(size) {
  document.getElementById('content').style.fontSize = size + 'px';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="smallText" onclick="changeTextSize(10);" class="mx-2 my-2 px-2">
                    small
                </button>
  <button id="normalText" onclick="changeTextSize(20);" class="mx-2 my-2 px-2">
                    normal
                </button>
  <button id="largeText" onclick="changeTextSize(40);" class="mx-2 my-2 px-2">
                    large
                </button>
</div>

<div id="content">
  sample text
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but what is that 'px'

Comment: `px` means the pixels, we can provide font size in different ways like `font-size: 15px;`, `font-size: large;`, `font-size: 150%;`. Here i am using `px`, thats why I append px at the end of value.